# Unable to launch an AVD Emulator: PANIC: Could not open: /home/baldur/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_7_by_Google.ini

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, qt-necessitas

I have been looking around online for tutorials on how to get started with development of Qt & OpenCV applications for Android devices, in particular a Nexus 7 running Android 4.2.2. By fooling around, I was able to create an Emulator and run on a certain Android Virtual Device (under Ubuntu Linux 12.10).

I am now trying to take on a more systematic and meticulous approach and better understand what I am doing. I uninstalled the Qt/Necessitas SDK and reinstalled. I am now having the following problems:

- When trying to launch an Android Emulator using a Nexus 7 target
  from the Device Definitions’ (i.e., a known device configuration), I
  receive the following type of an error:

**Starting emulator for AVD ‘AVD_for_Nexus_7_by_Google;
PANIC: Could not open: /home/baldur/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_7_by_Google.ini**

- When trying to launch an Android Emulator using my own custom
  definition of an Android Virtual Device, I receive the following
  error:

**Emulator: ERROR: This AVD’s configuration is missing a kernel file!!**

- With the device 'AVD_for_Nexus_7_by_Google' created, I create on ‘Start’ in the AVD Manager. Nothing happens, the Qt Creator turns gray-ish, and I just keep waiting. Necessitas seems to hang up.
- I can only run the AVD Virtual Device Manager if I run the Necessitas through sudo, after installation.

Any pointers on how to fix these problems would be most welcomed.

Best regards,
Baldur

P.S. I am including a few images that hopefully provide a reasonably good idea of what is going on.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the path to the virtual device definition exists, has the right permissions along the entire folder path, and actually still contains the definition file?

```
/home/baldur/.android/avd/AVD_for_Nexus_7_by_Google.ini
```

Have you moved any folders around, such as the install locations of your IDE?

I'm used to the windows Eclipse Android Development bundle.  It has settings were you can change the path to the folder to your device definitions.  Is the same true for yours, and if so, Is the path set to your Nexus definition?  NOTE: Not to the file that defines the INSTANCE of the AVD you create (you could make many), but to the file that tells your IDE the settings for creation OF an instance of a Nexus 7-like AVD ( analagous to the default class definition that tells your IDE what properties a Nexus 7 has).

Comment: **Thanks a lot, Ace!** With everything on my plate, I may not be able to get back to this right away (allow me some time). But I do believe you are fundamentally correct.